# Sub App_WorkbookBeforeSave doesn't work on VBA Add-in/Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling, subroutine

I am going to show a `MessageBox` before save workbook. I have tried with event handler `Sub App_WorkbookBeforeSave()` and `Sub Workbook_BeforeSave` but both doesn't work! Why?

There are my Sub in addin:

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, _
                                   ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Good bye! Data is save."
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Good bye! Data is save."
End Sub
```

*UPDATE*

I was put them in `ThisWorkbook` modules belong to `Microsoft Excel Objects`

Comment: The second piece of code looks good, check that macros are enabled and that you have not disable events.

Comment: Your `Workbook_BeforeSave` works for me... Are you sure you put it in the `ThisWorkbook` module?

Comment: Yep, I was put it in `ThisWorkbook` belong to `Microsoft Excel Objects`

Comment: If the Workbook_BeforeSave is in the addin's workbook module then it's not going to be fired when another workbook is saved. Is that what you're trying to capture?  If so then you need to set up some application-level events.  Google for "Excel application events"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of functionality requires...

- The code to be in ThisWorkbook module of the Add-In, **OR**
- Using a class to hold the event handling code, while still kicking it off in the ThisWorkbook module

Either way, you need to create an instance of a *WithEvents* Application object which, while you don't touch the object directly after you create it, enables the events to be captured.

I like the second option (cleaner, makes you look like a boss, etc.).  Create a class and call it something.  I like to call my class **ImAGoodListener**.  In the class, include the appropriate Subs for any application events you want to use

```
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox "Good bye!"
End Sub
```

With the arguments, you can do cool and mischievous things like prevent the workbook from being saved...

(I like *On Error Resume Next* for this so we don't risk not allowing a user to save his/her workbook should our code go haywire)

In the **ThisWorkbook** module put something like this...

```
Dim objAppLis As New ImAGoodListener

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set objAppLis.App = Application
End Sub
```

This will start the event listening when your Add-In is initially opened.

Alternatively, if you're using CustomUI for the ribbon, you use a Ribbon Onload event to trigger the start of listening (I do this when my events are used primarily for ribbon behavior so I can easy disable listening in the CustomUI xml).

Some other application events of use are:

- App_SheetActivate
- App_WorkbookActivate
- App_WorkbookOpen
- App_WorkbookBeforeClose
- App_WorkbookBeforeSave

Here's a **[list of all events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff846466.aspx)**, but note that some of them are workbook (event handlers start with *Workbook_* events which won't work for this sort of thing.

Chip goes into great detail about these sort of events on his site **[here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx)**.